# Unable to boot iMac, folder with question mark on boot, failed to format drive

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, imac, startup

I'm unable to boot an iMac with Mac Os Ventura, every time I switch on the computer a folder with a question mark appears on screen.

I just hope the drive is not damage and that I might be doing something wrong. I have no previous experience with a Mac.

Machine: iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5 pulgadas, 2017)

I have tried to format the hardrive, resetting the fusion drive via the terminal, but it's incapable of finishing the process.

Mac Os Ventura currently "installed".

[image]

When running resetFusion command on the terminal shows error: Error: -69842: Couldn't mount disk Could not perform or finish the operation: -69842 (Couldn't mount disk)

[image]

Tried running veryfyDisk (last attemp on the following screenshot):

[image]

Disk info for disk0:

[image]

Extra info when running the safe boot utilities:

[image]

There is no data I wish to keep in the drive, I prefer to wipe all data from the drive (there shouldn't be anything anyway).

Comment: The output `Smart Status: Failing` (shown in one of the images you posted) can not be a good thing. See Wikipedia article on [Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology). If you decide to repair the Mac, I would remove the SATA HDD and replace the PCIe SSD with a larger size. For example, there is the [OWC Aura Pro X2](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-21.5-inch/2013-2019).